# Bouncy Castle C# PGP Decryption example

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

I have been looking all day yesterday, and I can't seem to find a working example of PGP decryption using Bouncy Castle in c#

Comment: take a look at http://blog.mrjaredpowell.com/2010/Automate_decryption_Bouncy_Castle.htm    or at the other so question with links to examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987699/pgp-encryption-and-decryption-using-bouncycastle-c-sharp

Comment: The blog post seems to be Java. not C#. I am trying to port the code though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally got it to work. The main issue I had with other samples was the fact that the private key ring I had included a key for signing which was coming up first when trying to load the key for decryption. This is why why I had to add a check for the `ElGamalPrivateKeyParameters` type on the key.

Below is my code. Not very clean, but it works.

```
        private static PgpPrivateKey GetPrivateKey(string privateKeyPath)
    {
        using (Stream keyIn = File.OpenRead(privateKeyPath))
        using (Stream inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(keyIn))
        {
            PgpSecretKeyRingBundle secretKeyRingBundle = new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(inputStream);

            PgpSecretKey key = null;
            foreach (PgpSecretKeyRing kRing in secretKeyRingBundle.GetKeyRings())
            {
                foreach (PgpSecretKey secretKey in kRing.GetSecretKeys())
                {
                    PgpPrivateKey privKey = secretKey.ExtractPrivateKey("1234567890".ToCharArray());

                    if (privKey.Key.GetType() ==
                        typeof (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ElGamalPrivateKeyParameters))
                        //Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ElGamalPrivateKeyParameters
                    {
                        return privKey;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        
        return null;
    }





    public static void Decrypt(Stream input, string outputpath, String privateKeyPath)
    {
        input = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(input);
        try
        {
            PgpObjectFactory pgpObjF = new PgpObjectFactory(input);
            PgpEncryptedDataList enc;
            PgpObject obj = pgpObjF.NextPgpObject();
            if (obj is PgpEncryptedDataList)
            {
                enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)obj;
            }
            else
            {
                enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)pgpObjF.NextPgpObject();
            }

       


            
            PgpPrivateKey privKey = GetPrivateKey(privateKeyPath);


            PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = enc.GetEncryptedDataObjects().Cast<PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData>().First();
            Stream clear;
            clear = pbe.GetDataStream(privKey);
            PgpObjectFactory plainFact = new PgpObjectFactory(clear);
            PgpObject message = plainFact.NextPgpObject();
            if (message is PgpCompressedData)
            {
                PgpCompressedData cData = (PgpCompressedData)message;
                Stream compDataIn = cData.GetDataStream();
                PgpObjectFactory o = new PgpObjectFactory(compDataIn);
                message = o.NextPgpObject();
                if (message is PgpOnePassSignatureList)
                {
                    message = o.NextPgpObject();
                    PgpLiteralData Ld = null;
                    Ld = (PgpLiteralData)message;
                    Stream output = File.Create(outputpath + "\\" + Ld.FileName);
                    Stream unc = Ld.GetInputStream();
                    Streams.PipeAll(unc, output);
                }
                else
                {
                    PgpLiteralData Ld = null;
                    Ld = (PgpLiteralData)message;
                    //Stream output = File.Create(outputpath + "\\" + Ld.FileName);
                    Stream output = File.Create(outputpath);
                    Stream unc = Ld.GetInputStream();
                    Streams.PipeAll(unc, output);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @GeorgePligor: Hi, I am very new to PGP have have to encrypt my csv in pgp format for some requirment, I have found code to implement that but still struggling to undersatand keystore and Keys. Could you suggest from where i can get keys? Public and private.

Comment: not working for me `if (message is PgpCompressedData)` always false

Comment: My 'message is PgpCompressedData' is true but then 'message = o.NextPgpObject();' is always null, any idea about it? Also I do not get ElGamalKeyParameters key type but keys of type - RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters only...

Comment: I realize this was awhile ago, but the line `var akp = new AsymmetricKeyParameter(true);`  gives the error: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface ( Furthermore, why is it there in the first place, you are not even using the variable akp in that block).

Comment: @ron Will this work even for 1 GB data?

Answer (score 7):

I was running into issues with Ron Harlev's Decrypt function holding the output file until the program was terminated. I added a few using statements around the Stream's to overcome this issue. I also replaced the hard coded passphrase in favor of an input argument. I hope somebody finds this useful.

```
private static bool DecryptFile(Stream inputStream, string outputDir, char[] passPhrase, string privateKeyLoc)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var newStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream))
            {
                PgpObjectFactory pgpObjF = new PgpObjectFactory(newStream);
                PgpEncryptedDataList enc;
                PgpObject obj = pgpObjF.NextPgpObject();
                if (obj is PgpEncryptedDataList)
                {
                    enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)obj;
                }
                else
                {
                    enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)pgpObjF.NextPgpObject();
                }

                PgpPrivateKey privKey = GetPrivateKey(privateKeyLoc, passPhrase, logger);

                PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = enc.GetEncryptedDataObjects().Cast<PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData>().First();

                using (Stream clear = pbe.GetDataStream(privKey))
                {
                    PgpObjectFactory plainFact = new PgpObjectFactory(clear);
                    PgpObject message = plainFact.NextPgpObject();

                    if (message is PgpCompressedData)
                    {
                        PgpCompressedData cData = (PgpCompressedData)message;
                        Stream compDataIn = cData.GetDataStream();
                        PgpObjectFactory o = new PgpObjectFactory(compDataIn);
                        message = o.NextPgpObject();
                        if (message is PgpOnePassSignatureList)
                        {
                            message = o.NextPgpObject();
                        }
                        PgpLiteralData Ld = null;
                        Ld = (PgpLiteralData)message;
                        using (Stream output = File.Create(outputDir + "\\" + Ld.FileName))
                        {
                            Stream unc = Ld.GetInputStream();
                            Streams.PipeAll(unc, output);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```