# PGP encryption in windows 2012 R2 server using VB.NET program

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, windows-server-2012-r2, pgp

We have a windows service program written in vb.NET (framework 4). This service will pick up the file from path A, processes it and creates output file(XML file) to path B. This output file is in .IN type.
We want to perform encryption on this .IN file and convert it into .PGP type which is later picked up through FTP. 
Previously we were using cryptocx v5 in our code in windows 2003 server and here encryption worked perfectly.
Now we have migrated our application to windows 2012 R2 server (64 bit) and here while performing encryption we are getting an error pop up.

[image]

We tried installing cryptocx v5 and V7 software’s, but we are getting same error pop up.

How to perform encryption (.pgp) on our windows 2012 R2 server (.net Framework 4)?

Comment: So you need to install some kind of additional license for that component on your server, if it used to work you presumable have one so you need to email the publisher and ask how to transfer it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to encrypt/decrypt/sign using PGP and you're not stuck on using cryptocx I'd suggest you take a look at PGP packages in NuGet.

For example Bouncycastle seems to be pretty popular, and you can find [several](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/kim/2009/01/23/pgp-zip-encrypted-files-with-c/), [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987699/pgp-encryption-and-decryption-using-bouncycastle-c-sharp) resources with a quick search.

I don't know that it's an option, but you might want to consider just encrypting them manually. If you go that route I'd suggest you take a look at [gpg4win](https://www.gpg4win.org/) and pick one of the several user-friendly front ends (I've used [kleopatra](http://openpgp.org/software/kleopatra/). It makes things pretty straightforward.)