# Using mutiple keys for Bouncy Castle C# API

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pgp

I am writing a program in C# to encrypt files with a private and public pgp key. I am very new to PGP and C# but I am getting a hang of it. Can some point me in the right direction on how to use Bouncy Castle C# API to use multiple keys.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at some examples and source code since you are new to pgp , a good tutorial can be found [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/kim/archive/2009/01/23/pgp-zip-encrypted-files-with-c.aspx) and also you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660160/partialinputstream-during-bouncycastle-pgp-decryption) , 
also you can fide some C# examples in the BouncyCastle [site](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/)

Comment: I found another way instead of using the Bouncy Castle API. Since I am developing on Linux with Mono and C#. I decided to use Process.Start on GPG and the arguments followed. This seems to work but I have had issues decrypting it.

Comment: It works now. I can decrypt my files and stuff. This is cool not having to rely on an API. Thanks for the examples, I will take a look into it though.

Comment: First link doesn't work, and second doesn't provide an answer.